# NodeJS npm can't access internet. Error Code ETIMEDOUT after a few minutes of freeze

Tags: ubuntu, node.js

I was trying to install the modules for nodejs  project. I ran `npm i` which for some reason froze at progress bar which is shown when adding modules, after a few minutes it just ended up with an error saying

```bash
https://registry.npmjs.org/bcrypt failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700:83b3:80e2:e43b:1d:6810:1023:443
65 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/minipass-fetch/lib/index.js:130:14)
65 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:512:28)
65 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:495:9)
65 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:524:35)
65 verbose stack     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
65 verbose stack     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
65 verbose stack     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
66 verbose cwd /home/rick/GoogleSolutions_Project_Backend
67 verbose Linux 5.19.0-35-generic
68 verbose node v19.8.1
69 verbose npm  v9.5.1
70 error code ETIMEDOUT
71 error syscall connect
72 error errno ETIMEDOUT
73 error network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/bcrypt failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700:83b3:80e2:e43b:1d:6810:1023:443
74 error network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
74 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
74 error network
74 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
74 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
75 verbose exit 1
76 timing npm Completed in 3225842ms
77 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1679241527055
78 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:loadTrees 1679241527057
79 verbose code 1
80 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
80 error     /home/rick/.npm/_logs/2023-03-19T15_58_47_022Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried installing a global package using `npm i -g bootstrap`, it still gave me the same error.

Full log: https://pastebin.com/Y2XrJgHR 
OS Version: Ubuntu Jammy 22.04 LTS

Comment: You're using IPv6.  Are you sure that you can reach registry.npmjs.org:443 from "your" computer?  `nc -zv registry.npmjs.org 443` will tell you.

Comment: @RonJohn I tried it and I don't think I can reach the address, output from `nc -zv registry.npmjs.org 443` :
`nc: connect to registry.npmjs.org (2606:4700:83b3:80e2:e41b:4a1:6810:1023) port 443 (tcp) failed: Connection timed out
Connection to registry.npmjs.org (104.16.24.35) 443 port [tcp/https] succeeded!`

It looks like I can connect through IPv4 but not IPv6

Comment: Use `mtr` to see where a firewall stops progress.

Comment: @RonJohn I'm sorry I'm not really familiar with `mtr`, I tried running `mtr --report -6 -P 443 registry.npmjs.org`, the output was `Start: 2023-03-20T10:16:43+0530
HOST: rick-Aspire-A515-52G        Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev`

Comment: `time mtr --report -c3 -6 -P 443 registry.npmjs.org` took 8 seconds on my system.  Here's the full output: https://pastebin.com/XmBWZC5m

Comment: @RonJohn here is my output fot the same command:
`Start: 2023-03-20T10:27:35+0530
HOST: rick-Aspire-A515-52G        Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
mtr --report -c3 -6 -P 443 registry.npmjs.org  0.00s user 0.01s system 0% cpu 8.593 total`

I just tried to run npm with warp-cli connected, it seems to working with clouflair warp